# When i try to add ZXing.Net.Mobile.forms in xamrin forms and compile then it shows errors

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

i want to create the barcode reader app, and when i try to add ZXing.Net.Mobile.forms library and compile the code below then it is showing me errors.

> MainActivity.xamal.cs
>       `

```
    private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var scan = new ZXingScannerPage();
        await Navigation.PushAsync(scan);

        scan.OnScanResult += (result) => { Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
        {
            await Navigation.PopAsync();
            barcode.Text = result.Text;
        }); };
    }
```

> Errors

```
When i try to compile the project these erorr are coming`
```

[image: This is the errors coming when i compile the project]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have `Zxing.Net.Mobile.Forms` installed in all three projects. Android has the additional requirement of needing `ZXing.Net.Mobile` installed. Install that in your Android project and it should fix your issue.

Comment: Thank you dear for you quick response, now your anwer fixed my problem and now new proplem occurs, when i press the Scan button then it is throwing the exception. System.MissingMethodException: 'Method not found: void ZXing.Mobile.ZXingSurfaceView..ctor(Android.App.Activity,ZXing.Mobile.MobileBarcodeScanningOptions)'

Comment: Did you initialize? you need to initialize in your ```MainActivity.cs``` on Android.

```ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms.Android.Platform.Init();```

And in AppDelegate.cs

```ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms.iOS.Platform.Init();```

Comment: Yes, but again throwing the same exception